# Unable to share Windows 10 folder to Everyone

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares

I am unable to access shared folders on exFat USB drives on a Windows 10 computer without entering user name and password (from Raspbian, don't have other computers at hand).

1. Password Protection is turned off in the Network and Sharing Center, so under the Sharing tab of each folder properties, Password Protection reads "People without a user account and password for this computer can access folders shared with everyone."
2. Under the Sharing tab, Click the "Share..." button, under the "Choose people to share with" popup, only the admin/owner account is visible. Add Everyone and Guest permissions, but as soon as I click the "Share" button, Everyone and Guest are removed from the list.
3. Under Advanced Sharing, I CAN add Everyone and Guest through the Permissions button, however, it has no effect - Everyone and Guest are still missing from "Choose people to share with", and accessing the share remotely still requires me to enter user name and password.

I am at a lost, help please.